# why can't i render what I want with getOptionLabel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm using `getOptionLabel` from material-ui but I don't know why it doesn't work fine.

I want to select from an array of elements (not objects). If I write `getOptionLabel={props.roles}` doesn't run and
in the code I wrote below I have as a result all the elements of the array for each row.

What is wrong?

```
<AutoComplete
  multiple
  id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
  options={props.roles}
  disableCloseOnSelect
  getOptionLabel={(options) => `${options}`}
  renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Checkbox
        icon={icon}
        checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
        style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
        checked={selected}
      />
      {props.roles}
    </React.Fragment>
  )}
  style={{ width: 500 }}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      variant="outlined"
      label="props.roles"
      placeholder="Available Roles"
    />
  )}
/>
```